# What wrong am I doing in Content Provider queries for multiple Tables?

Tags: java, android

[table structure][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0cJ3.jpg
I have these two tables and want to retrieve transaction's table data using content provider ( THIS DB NEEDS TO BE SHARED TO OTHER APP). I have implemented code for these too. Here it is

```
case TRANSACTION:

                        SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
                        sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("TransactionTable  INNER JOIN Products ON TransactionTable.product_id_in_product_table = Products._ID");
                        HashMap<String,String> columnprojection = new HashMap<String,String>();
                       columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry._ID , myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + myTransactionEntry._ID + "AS" + "TID" );
                        columnprojection.put("PRODUCT NAME ",  myDbEntry.TABLE_NAME       + "." +myDbEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " AS " + "PNAME");
                        columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGED,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHANGED + " AS " + "QTY");
                        columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE + " AS " + "TTYPE");
                        columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE + " AS " + "TDATE");
                        columnprojection.put(myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_ANYREMARK,myTransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +myTransactionEntry.COLUMN_ANYREMARK+ " AS " + "TREMARK");

                        sqLiteQueryBuilder.setProjectionMap(columnprojection);
                    c = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(db,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);


                break;
```

But I am getting error in logcat as

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.balaji/com.example.balaji.DashBoard}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column product_id_in_product_table
```

What wrong am I doing here?

```
my CustomCursorAdatper's coding here
   mytransid.setText( String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TID"))));
        myproductid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PNAME")));
        myproductquantity_changed.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("QTY"))));
        myproduct_type_of_trns.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(("TTYPE")))));
        myproduct_timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(("TDATE")))));
```

Alos, THE column "PNAME" returns -1 in the line cursor.getColumnIndex("PNAME");
I DON'T KNOW WHY ?
WHY IT IS NOT INCLUDED IN THE PROJECTION NAME?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer.
I had to include product_id_in_product_table in projection map because every column need to be present from TransactionTable.
And in the adapter , getColumnIndex("PNAME") was returning -1 because in SQLiteBuilder's query method I was using projection array instead of setting it to null.
Thanks for this guy. I get to know the exact meaning of setProjectionMap()
[https://blog.mousetech.com/android-projection-maps-explained/]